# pass a value inside request.getAttribute tag using jsp

Tags: jsp, struts, javabeans

Hope someone can help me out on this problem:

How do I pass a value inside the getAttribute tag? For example i've been trying to do this:

```
(request.getAttribute(<bean:write name="region" property="id" />) == "true")
```

but this doesn't work and I know the value of my bean:write is correct.

So what is the correct why to do this? Can I define the bean:write outside the getAttribute tag and then use a different way to put it in there? Like this:

```
<bean:define id="someValue" name="region" property="id"/>
(request.getAttribute(${someValue}) == "true") ?
```

Thanks!

Regards
Francois

Comment: Ok I got it to work... <bean:define id="someValue" name="region" property="id"/>
(request.getAttribute(someValue) == "true")

Comment: Why are you even *trying* to do it like this?